# how to config ruport in the environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, ruport

i have installed ruport gem along with its ruport-utils packages and act_as_reportable gem too....
e

"Ash::Application.initialize!

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
      config.after_initialize do 
       require "ruport" 
    end
   end" 
when executing this in the environment.rb file... it shows this "

c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:63:in `inherited': You cannot have more than one Rails::Application (RuntimeError)"
what am i doing wrong.... can somebody help me with properly configuration method of ruport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to do so, and be sure that Ruport is loaded at the proper time, is to add the code to require Ruport to a config.after_initialize block. The relevant section of the configuration file is shown below.

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.after_initialize do 
      require "ruport" 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ok found wht i was doing wrong... apparently the source i was referring for was for earlier verion... with the new one just put this " config.autoload_paths += %W(::RAILS.root.to_s/app/reports) " in the config/environments/development.rb file , also specify yur gem in the gemfile and do a bundle insatll. and and also for generating textile file ie for rendering the report in html format you would be required to install RedCloth gem version 3.0.3(thats what i have installed in my system.)